# Why do i get an extra word?

Tags: c++

> Write and test your own function char * function1 (char * string1) in the program, removing the initial spaces from string1, returning the modified string1 as the result. The function1 function could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char *space( char *string1 );
int main() {
    char str[] = "   Hello cpp", *newstr;

    cout << "first" << str << "end" << endl;    // first   Hello cppend

    newstr = space( str );

    cout << "first" << str << "end" << endl;    // firstHello cppend

    cout << "first" << newstr << "end" << endl;    // firstHello cppend
    return 0;

}
char *space( char *str ) {

    int j = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < strlen( str ); i++ ) {
        if ( str[i] != ' ' ) {
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

This is my code, and as a result it gives me:

```
first   Hello cppsec // OK
firstHellocpp cppsec // not OK, it's should be firstHello cppend
firstHellocpp cppsec // not OK, it's should be firstHello cppend
```

What is wrong with this? I know that i should remove first spaces.
I'm doing it  but it adds extra "cpp" after Hello...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210479/discussion-on-question-by-xyz9-why-do-i-get-an-extra-word).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is why there is an extra word.
(I.e. you did not ask for a program which matches the homework assignment.)
So I answer the asked question, basically according to the compromise described here:
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

You copy the non-blank parts of the string to the beginning.
You do however not terminate that initial part, hence the last number-of-blanks characters from the end of the string are still in output.

You can fix by inserting a termination before the return:

```
str[j]='\0';
return str;
```

Result:

```
first   Hello cppend
firstHellocppend
firstHellocppend
```

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks for your input. I have commented that my answer matches the asked question, which is not "What program can I hand in to solve this homework?"

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the question was specific after your edit. so I deleted my comment :)

Comment: @ChrisMM I liked your comment and it made me aware of the misunderstanding which lazy readers could have because of the suboptimal formatting and prhasing of the question... I wish more people would understand that "I can write code to match that assignment." is not an answer... Your answer below is different, it has an explanation and just goes beyond the minimum,  so I do not mean you...

Comment: I just wanted to express respect and gratitude to the person who downvoted this answer initially (anonymously which is of course normal and correct, though somewhat frustrating) and then obviously came back later to check on it, found it improved and un-downvoted. I appreciate the effort and seriousness you seem to be investing in your voting. (And just to be totally clear, there is no sarcasm, cynicism or anything intended here.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the NULL character of `str`, so before your return you would have `str[j] = '\0';`. This tells C-strings where they finish, otherwise it keeps reading until it finds the null character.

If your ultimate goal is to remove the first set of spaces, then your code will not do that. Instead it effectively removes all spaces. Below is a version with comments that removes the first set of spaces only:

```
char *space( char *str ) {
    int j = 0, i;
    // Keep this outside the loop header, so that it doesn't calculate strlen multiple times
    const size_t len = strlen( str );
    // Find the first space
    for ( i = 0; i < len && str[i] != ' '; ++i ) {}
    // This is now your starting position
    j = i;
    // Find the first non-space after the first space
    while ( str[i] == ' ' && i < len ) ++i;
    // Move everything up in the array to overwrite those spaces
    while ( i < len ) {
        str[j++] = str[i++];
    }
    // Set the null character of the string so that it has a new end
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Working example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZSbG5n)